# Cannot connect to Google Cloud SQL instance from Run or Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect to my Cloud SQL instance from a Cloud Function and Cloud run instance.
This Cloud SQL instance has a private IP address and VPC network `backend`.
Both my Function and Run instance are attacked to this VPC network `backend` as wel, with a VPC connector. All are in the same region.

All private IPs are in the `10.0.0.0` space, while I have a firewall rule that accepts all ports coming from `10.0.0.0/8`.
I see no firewall logs.

However, I receive i/o timeouts whenever trying to connect to `private-sql-ip:3306` from either.
Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to say anything without exact details of VPC connector and VPC netowrk, and firewall?

Comment: @vitooh : 
VPC: `backend, europe-west1 backend-eu-west1, 10.1.0.0/16, gateway 10.1.0.1`
VPC Connector: ` backend-vpc-connector2 backend europe-west1 10.10.0.0/28`
Firewall: `default-allow-internal
Incoming, Apply to all
IP-ranges: 10.128.0.0/9, 10.0.0.0/8
tcp:0-65535
udp:0-65535
icmp
Allow
65534
default
Enabled
0`

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to replicate it from this information. I suggest to go to page https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/getting-support and try to get the support accordingly to the instruction